# Swift gesture delegates

Tags: ios, iphone, maps, gesture

I'm trying to implement HERE maps SDK gestures. I added delegate and didRecivePan function. The pan gesture is recognized by the application.
**Problem** is that my mapView gets frozen for the time my pan gesture is being used and it creates lagging like map scrolling which makes UX really annoying. Is there anyway this can be resolved.

```
var follow : Bool = true;

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: NMAMapView!

let positionManager = NMAPositioningManager.self
let gestureMarker = NMAMapMarker.self   

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.gestureDelegate = self
}

@objc func didLosePosition(){ print("Position lost")}

@objc func positionDidUpdate(){
    /* Possible solution but an ugly one!
    if(follow == true){
        mapView.gestureDelegate = self
    }else if(follow == false){
        mapView.gestureDelegate = nil
    }*/
    print("Follow \(follow)")
    print("position updated")
    let position = positionManager.sharedInstance().currentPosition
    print(position!.coordinates ?? "xx")
    if(follow){
    mapView.set(geoCenter:(position?.coordinates)!,animation: .linear)
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if(positionManager.sharedInstance().startPositioning()){
        // Register to positioning manager notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.positionDidUpdate), name: NSNotification.Name.NMAPositioningManagerDidUpdatePosition, object: positionManager.sharedInstance())
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.didLosePosition), name: NSNotification.Name.NMAPositioningManagerDidLosePosition, object: positionManager.sharedInstance())
    }

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    mapView.zoomLevel = 17
    mapView.set(geoCenter: NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude:  45.921189263505788, longitude: 14.234863696633125),
                animation: .linear)
    let mapMarker = NMAMapMarker(geoCoordinates: NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude:  45.921189263505788, longitude: 14.234863696633125), icon: NMAImage(uiImage: UIImage(named: "driver") ?? UIImage())!)
    mapView.positionIndicator.isVisible = true;
    mapView.positionIndicator.isAccuracyIndicatorVisible = true
    mapView.positionIndicator.set(displayObject: mapMarker, toLayer: NMAMapLayerType.foreground)
    mapView.copyrightLogoPosition = NMALayoutPosition.centerRight
}

func mapView(_ mapView: NMAMapView, didReceivePan translation: CGPoint, at location: CGPoint) {
    follow = false

}

@IBAction func followButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    follow = true
    mapView.set(geoCenter: (positionManager.sharedInstance().currentPosition?.coordinates)!,
                animation: .linear)
    mapView.zoomLevel = 17
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Copy/Paste code, not screenshot. If another user have an issue, he might not find it by "searching screenshot". Also, it you have complicate lines, it's easier for us to do a copy/paste and try it/point out the mistake.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, fixed it :)